# sqlquery to mysql query

Tags: mysql

I'm using this query in sqlserver and need same query in mysql .. i'm new in mysql .. please help me out to solve this query.

```
    DECLARE @sql AS nvarchar(max)
    set @sql=''
    set @sql='Select * From('
    SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
    SELECT name  FROM ['+ SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) +'].[' + name + ']
    UNION ALL '
    FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T where table_name like 'Custom%'
    SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 0, len(@sql)-9)
    print @sql
```

regards

Answer (score 0):

try

```
set @sql = '';
set @sql='Select * From(';
SELECT @sql = @sql + N'
    SELECT name  FROM ['+ TABLE_SCHEMA +'].[' + TABLE_NAME + ']
    UNION ALL '
    FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T where table_name like 'Custom%';

SELECT @sql = SUBSTRING(@sql, 0, length(@sql)-9);
select @sql
```

Comment: thanx for reply juergen d 
when i use this query i get

Comment: I'm getting this errorTruncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ']
    UNION ALL '
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'custom_70007'
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'SELECT name  FROM ['
Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'custom_70014'